# How can i make the python program to check linux services

Tags: python, linux, network-programming, centos

I want to make simple python script , which i can run on cron job. i just want to see if these services are currently running or stopped

```
Httpd
mysql
```

How should i check them with python.

Do i need to parse the output of `netstat -tlnp`

Comment: You can take a look at psutil to do this. Found here; https://code.google.com/p/psutil/

Comment: If you like one of the answers it is a nice gesture to mark one as "Your favorite Answer". It not only rewards the people who answered, but can also help people in the future who have the same question.

Answer (score 12):

```
   import subprocess
    
    
    service = "apache2"
    
    p =  subprocess.Popen(["systemctl", "is-active",  service], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    (output, err) = p.communicate()
    output = output.decode('utf-8')
    
    print(output)
```

The Python program will check if the service is running. If it running, the output will be "active" otherwise the output will be "inactive".

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 5):

Use psutils class. Its fantastic and cross platform.. Following are the functional usage..

```
import psutil
>>> psutil.get_pid_list()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 46, 48, 50, 51, 178, 182, 222, 223, 224,
268, 1215, 1216, 1220, 1221, 1243, 1244, 1301, 1601, 2237, 2355,
2637, 2774, 3932, 4176, 4177, 4185, 4187, 4189, 4225, 4243, 4245,
4263, 4282, 4306, 4311, 4312, 4313, 4314, 4337, 4339, 4357, 4358,
4363, 4383, 4395, 4408, 4433, 4443, 4445, 4446, 5167, 5234, 5235,
5252, 5318, 5424, 5644, 6987, 7054, 7055, 7071]
>>>
>>> p = psutil.Process(7055)
>>> p.name
'python'
>>> p.exe
'/usr/bin/python'
>>> p.getcwd()
'/home/giampaolo'
>>> p.cmdline
['/usr/bin/python', 'main.py']
>>>
>>> str(p.status)
'running'
>>> p.username
'giampaolo'
>>> p.create_time
1267551141.5019531
>>> p.terminal
'/dev/pts/0'
>>>
>>> p.uids
user(real=1000, effective=1000, saved=1000)
>>> p.gids
group(real=1000, effective=1000, saved=1000)
>>>
>>> p.get_cpu_times()
cputimes(user=1.02, system=0.31)
>>> p.get_cpu_percent(interval=1.0)
12.1
>>> p.get_cpu_affinity()
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> p.set_cpu_affinity([0])
>>>
>>> p.get_memory_percent()
0.63423
>>> p.get_memory_info()
meminfo(rss=7471104, vms=68513792)
>>> p.get_ext_memory_info()
meminfo(rss=9662464, vms=49192960, shared=3612672, text=2564096, lib=0,     
data=5754880,dirty=0)
>>> p.get_memory_maps()
[mmap(path='/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.15.so', rss=16384, anonymous=8192, swap=0),
 mmap(path='/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so', rss=6384, anonymous=15, swap=0),
 mmap(path='/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0', rss=34124, anonymous=1245,  
swap=0),
 mmap(path='[heap]', rss=54653, anonymous=8192, swap=0),
 mmap(path='[stack]', rss=1542, anonymous=166, swap=0),
 ...]
>>>
>>> p.get_io_counters()
io(read_count=478001, write_count=59371, read_bytes=700416, write_bytes=69632)
>>>
>>> p.get_open_files()
[openfile(path='/home/giampaolo/svn/psutil/somefile', fd=3)]
>>>
>>> p.get_connections()
[connection(fd=115, family=2, type=1, local_address=('10.0.0.1', 48776),
            remote_address=('93.186.135.91', 80), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 connection(fd=117, family=2, type=1, local_address=('10.0.0.1', 43761),
            remote_address=('72.14.234.100', 80), status='CLOSING'),
 connection(fd=119, family=2, type=1, local_address=('10.0.0.1', 60759),
            remote_address=('72.14.234.104', 80), status='ESTABLISHED'),
 connection(fd=123, family=2, type=1, local_address=('10.0.0.1', 51314),
            remote_address=('72.14.234.83', 443), status='SYN_SENT')]
>>>
>>> p.get_num_threads()
4
>>> p.get_num_fds()
8
>>> p.get_num_ctx_switches()
amount(voluntary=78, involuntary=19)
>>>
>>> p.get_threads()
[thread(id=5234, user_time=22.5, system_time=9.2891),
 thread(id=5235, user_time=0.0, system_time=0.0),
 thread(id=5236, user_time=0.0, system_time=0.0),
 thread(id=5237, user_time=0.0707, system_time=1.1)]
>>>
>>> p.get_nice()
0
>>> p.set_nice(10)
>>>
>>> p.suspend()
>>> p.resume()
>>>
>>> p.terminate()
>>> p.wait(timeout=3)
0
>>>
>>> psutil.test()
USER         PID %CPU %MEM     VSZ     RSS TTY        START    TIME  COMMAND
root           1  0.0  0.0   24584    2240 ?          Jun17   00:00  init
root           2  0.0  0.0       0       0 ?          Jun17   00:00  kthreadd
root           3  0.0  0.0       0       0 ?          Jun17   00:05  ksoftirqd/0
...
giampaolo  31475  0.0  0.0   20760    3024 /dev/pts/0 Jun19   00:00  python2.4
giampaolo  31721  0.0  2.2  773060  181896 ?          00:04   10:30  chrome
root       31763  0.0  0.0       0       0 ?          00:05   00:00  kworker/0:1
>>>
```

Comment: I had a look myself at this module as well, but is it also possible to get a list of all processes by name instead of PID?

Comment: To use this, you need the package `python-psutil` installed. Then you can do things like:
`[p.name for p in psutil.get_process_list()]` to get a list of all the running programs. or `p.cmdline` if you want the full command.

Comment: I guess the new version has changed ... `Successfully installed psutil-3.0.1
# python get_service.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_service.py", line 3, in <module>
    pids = psutil.get_pid_list()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_pid_list'`. Now it seems to be simply `psutil.pids()`

Comment: p.name is a method; to get the name of the process end with () as in p.name()

Comment: I ended up using `processes = [psutil.Process(p).name() for p in psutil.pids()]`

Answer (score 4):

You could use the commands module to run the ps shell argument:

```
import commands
output = commands.getoutput('ps -A')
if 'Httpd' in output:
    print("Httpd is up an running!")
```

[edit] I just read up on the commands module, and although working fine, it seems to be deprecated since Python 2.6 and even removed in Python 3.x. So if you are on Python 3 or want to be ready for future porting to Python 3, you can use the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-A'])
if 'Httpd' in output:
    print("Httpd is up an running!")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use the subprocess module you can do this without spawning a shell, which the command module will do. (You probably don't need a separate shell for this and there might be some security concerns by doing so).

Note that this also gives you possibility to act on errors (see the err variable below), for example you can try to restart services that are down etc.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ps", "-a"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
if ('Httpd' in str(out)):
    print('Httpd running')
if ('mysql' in str(out)):
    print('mysql running')
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 2):

If your services are properly registered and support `status` reporting (init script or upstart job), Use the linux command

```
service <name> status
```

If the service is running, command will return exit code `0`

```
import os
import subprocess


def is_service_running(name):
    with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as hide_output:
        exit_code = subprocess.Popen(['service', name, 'status'], stdout=hide_output, stderr=hide_output).wait()
        return exit_code == 0


if not is_service_running('mysql'):
    print 'mysql is not running'
```

- the `os.devnull` is a bonus, to hide the output of the child process.

Comment: This looks great, but ran into an issue when the service I wanted to watch crashed, it went to status `Active: active (exited)` Apparently this still runs with `exitcode 0` so the script does not detect that it is down.  May be a problem with systemd, may be a problem with the service I'm watching, who knows... Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Butters: right... the status code of the Linux command `service` is zero, because IT ran to completion with no error.  Seems to me that you have identified your own solution: just look for `Active: active (exited)` to determine the state.  Adjust the "return" statement accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

i used the code of Jossef and I added some features

Thanks so Much Jossef

```
    import subprocess
    import os
    import subprocess
    import requests

    def is_service_running(name):
        with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as hide_output:
            exit_code = subprocess.Popen(['service', name, 'status'], stdout=hide_output, stderr=hide_output).wait()
            return exit_code == 0

# CLASS SLACK TO SEND NOTIFICATION
    class Slack:
        def __init__(self,report):
            webhook = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/T92JCJW59/B012Qxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            response = requests.post(webhook, json=report, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
            if response.ok:
                json_data = response.text
                self.result = json_data

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        if not is_service_running('mysqld'):
            print ('mysql is not running')
            os.system("systemctl restart mysqld")
            result_dict = ("*MICHELONE SLACK* \n*MYSQL DOWN IM GOING TO RESTART* ")
            slack_report = {"attachments": [{"fallback": "*MICHELONE SLACK*", "color": "#FF0000", "text": result_dict}]}
            slack_push_log = Slack(slack_report)
        else:
            print("ALL OK")
        if not is_service_running('httpd'):
            print('httpd is not running')
            os.system("systemctl restart httpd")
            result_dict = ("*MICHELONE SLACK* \n*APACHE DOWN IM GOING TO RESTART* ")
            slack_report = {"attachments": [{"fallback": "*MICHELONE SLACK*", "color": "#FF0000", "text": result_dict}]}
            slack_push_log = Slack(slack_report)

        else:
            print("ALL OK")
```