# Python code to get services and their statuses on linux

Tags: python, linux, service

I am trying to write a python program that can get a dictionary of **services** on a machine (either linux or windows).

Any entry on the dictionary is a made of {Service : Status} pairs.

This program will run every given seconds from the user.

I understood that the module psutils is providing the right tools because it's simplicity and cross-platform abilities.

Thus I wrote this code below. This code is getting the information from the system.

```
def getServiceDict():
    dict = {}
    if os.name == "nt":
        for service in psutil.win_service_iter():
            dict[service.name()] = service.status()
    elif os.name == "posix":
        for pid in psutil.pids():
            name = psutil.Process(pid).name()
            status = psutil.Process(pid).status()
            dict[name] = status

    return list
```

As you can see service listing in windows is quite straight forward , but on linux I found only a way to list processes and not services.

**How do I differentiate processes from services in linux**?

Is there an attribute that I can access through psutils? Maybe a different module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i make the python program to check linux services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541044/how-can-i-make-the-python-program-to-check-linux-services)

Comment: No. This question was about a specific service, with a simple one line output. I want to create a list of services and then check for their statuses. I don't know a bash command that can return a JSON of services for a machine to interpret